# Viewport of hidden android webview fragment not being set

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments, android-webview, viewport

I have a two fragments that contain webviews. I have been injecting javascript using webview.loadUrl() into the webViews to set the viewport (696 portrait, 953 landscape if you're curious). I have been using the show() and hide() fragment transactions to hide and show the fragments and preserve whatever web page was open when the user switches between them. The onConfigurationChange makes another loadUrl call to set the viewport of the webViews based on the new orientation.

The problem is that the fragment that is hidden does not get it's viewport set correctly if the orientation changes. The onConfigurationChange function is being called for both fragments (since they're just hidden) and the loadUrl call is being made to set the viewport but if I switch back to the hidden fragment, the viewport is still set for whatever the previous orientation was. If I change orientation again, it gets set correctly however now the hidden fragment is out of sync.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: could you elaborate on why you need to do this from JavaScript? Why doesn't a viewport meta tag with "width=device-width" work for you?

Comment: Post your fragment code, sounds as if you're setting the viewport on a hidden fragment but that is not the same instance that gets shown when you switch to it.  Maybe it's getting recreated unintentionally?